# How to create form with two input line on the same line?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created Bootstrap form with the following code :

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="GET" action="/startup/searchprojects">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="keywords">Key words</label> <input
                type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords"
                placeholder="keywords">
        </div>

            <div class="form-group example example-countries">
            <label class="sr-only" for="localisation">Country</label>
                <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="countries">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            <fmt:message key="search.button.title" />
        </button>
    </form>
```

The form display on the same line. two inputs text with the submit button on the same line.

But when i add Spring MVC form tags, the form changes. Each input went on one line. So i have one line for the keywords input, one line for the input country and one line for the submit button. My form is now vertical.
Here the spring mvc form :

```
<form:form class="form-inline" role="form" method="GET" commandName="search-form" action="/startup/searchprojects">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:label path="keywords" class="sr-only" for="keywords">Key words</form:label> 
        <form:input path="keywords" type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords"
            placeholder="key words"></form:input>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group example example-countries">
        <form:label path="country" class="sr-only" for="localisation">Country</form:label>
            <form:input path="country" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="countries"></form:input>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <fmt:message key="search.button.title" />
    </button>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Check the [bootstrap docs on inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

Comment: I use the documentation instructions but the css bootstrap are changed by spring mvc form tag

Comment: Could it be the `example` and `example-countries` classes interfere?

Comment: Bart i think it's form tags which interfere but i don't know really how it's happen. If i remove spring form tag. form displays as i want

Comment: Can you paste the final output from the page source?

Comment: Here is the source http://pastebin.com/ns37BP6e

Comment: The only thing left I can think of is a CSS rule on #search-form which might cause problems since the spring form tag will generate the id for the form.

Comment: You're right i've just add width on #search-form and it's work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjust width of  #search-form. It was problem of width.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting style="display: inline" in every div you use

> `<div style="display: inline"> some content</div>`